# Add a dialog box on application start up in c# / Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, dialog

An application where I need to fetch Email ID and password before starting the application. I need to get this information for processing, application is build using XAML/C# ? How can I achieve this using custom Dialog Box ?

thank you

Comment: @Basvo I have tried changing StartupUri & creating a whole new page.... But that's like calling a new page and getting a value. I want a dialog to be opened and get value from user

Comment: Maybe you can post your code?

Comment: @Basvo I don't have code right away . If you have anything helpful regarding this please post it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the type "App" autogenerated in new wpf applications (derived from Application) is set as Startup object (see Application properties). You may ...

a) replace this object with your own type that is instantiating App and calling App.run() after the credentials have been provided. Be sure to declare your entry method with [STAThread].

```
  [STAThread]      
  public static int Main()
  {
     MyOperations();
     var app = new App();
     app.Run();
  }
```

b)  Override OnStartup in App.xaml.cs:

```
  protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
  {
     base.OnStartup(e);
     MyOperations();
  }
```

EDIT: I may have missed the point. If your aim is to show another WPF window before showing the main one, you can use option b), but you may have to modify Application.Current.ShutdownMode before showing your login mask, or else the program will terminate after closing it.

So, this would be the content of the existing file App.xaml.cs (its hidden in the solution explorer, you have to expand App.xaml to see it).

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class App : Application
   {
      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
      {
         base.OnStartup(e);
         ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
         var loginWindow = new Login();
         loginWindow.ShowDialog();
         if (!loginWindow.LoggedIn)
         {
            Shutdown();
            return;
         }
         ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you share the file of demonstration so that I can understand .

Comment: I´m not sure if i do understand you... ;-) I updated my post to clarify that one would edit App.xaml.cs for this.